# lib packages of a Spring Boot application are separated, the main program class cannot be correctly called by other modules

Tags: java

When passing the entity class from the main program to Mybatis-Plus's QueryWrapper results in a ClassNotFoundException
Creating a new SqlSession

SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@43745a5e] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active

Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@43745a5e]

13:33:47.640 [http-nio-9083-exec-3] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'ew.sqlSegment != null and ew.sqlSegment != '' and ew.nonEmptyOfWhere'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: sqlSegment [com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: This is impossible to happen]] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.haitaiinc.service.impl.SwitchConfigServiceImpl

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:686)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.support.SerializedLambda$1.resolveClass(SerializedLambda.java:63)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1716)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1556)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)

at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.support.SerializedLambda.resolve(SerializedLambda.java:67)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.LambdaUtils.lambda$resolve$0(LambdaUtils.java:64)

at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.LambdaUtils.resolve(LambdaUtils.java:63)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.AbstractLambdaWrapper.columnToString(AbstractLambdaWrapper.java:72)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.AbstractLambdaWrapper.columnToString(AbstractLambdaWrapper.java:68)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.AbstractLambdaWrapper.columnToString(AbstractLambdaWrapper.java:39)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.AbstractWrapper.lambda$addCondition$ac69df92$1(AbstractWrapper.java:332)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)

at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)

at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.segments.NormalSegmentList.childrenSqlSegment(NormalSegmentList.java:89)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.segments.AbstractISegmentList.getSqlSegment(AbstractISegmentList.java:102)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.segments.MergeSegments.getSqlSegment(MergeSegments.java:72)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.conditions.AbstractWrapper.getSqlSegment(AbstractWrapper.java:432)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:881)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1691)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:60)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:147)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2719)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTNotEq.getValueBody(ASTNotEq.java:50)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTAnd.getValueBody(ASTAnd.java:61)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:493)

at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:457)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:46)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:34)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.TrimSqlNode.apply(TrimSqlNode.java:55)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:35)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)

at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:39)

at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:297)

at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)

at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)

at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.selectList(Unknown Source)

at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:223)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.executeForMany(MybatisMapperMethod.java:158)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:76)

at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:61)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.selectList(Unknown Source)

at com.haitaiinc.service.impl.SwitchConfigServiceImpl.getAllSwitchConfig(SwitchConfigServiceImpl.java:30)

at com.haitaiinc.controller.SwitchConfigController.getAllSwitchConfig(SwitchConfigController.java:26)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

modifying manifestEntries and discovering they are loaded by different classloaders